# XML to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, pandas

I have a XML file with thousands of lines like:

```
<Word x1="206" y1="120" x2="214" y2="144" font="Times-Roman" style="font-size:22pt">WORD</Word>
```

I want to convert it (all it's attributes) to `pandas` `dataframe`. To do that i could loop through the file using beautiful soup and insert the values row by row or create lists to be inserted as columns. However I would like to know if there's a more pythonic way of accomplishing what I described. Thank you in advance.

Code example:

```
x1list=[]
x2list=[]

for word in soup.page.findAll('word'):
    x1list.append(int(word['x1']))
    x2list.append(int(word['x2']))
df=DataFrame({'x1':x1list,'x2':x2list})
```

Comment: @eumiro: added a code example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataFrame.from_records([(int(word['x1']), int(word['x2']))
                        for word in soup.page.findAll('word')],
                       columns=('x1', 'x2'))
```