# Handling namespaces in XML with LXML obectify and pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas, lxml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to adapt a recipe to parse an xml feed (http://data.gov.uk/dataset/car-parks)

I can parse the document using objectify but the result comes out like this...

u"{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarPark = None [ObjectifiedElement]\n    {http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkRef = 4401 [IntElement]\n    {http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkName = 'Wallace Street' [StringElement]\n    {http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}Location = 'Galston' [StringElement]\n    {http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}Address = 'Henrietta Street--Galston--East Ayrshire' [StringElement]\n    {http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}Postcode = 'KA4 8HP' [StringElement]\n...

I've then used the code

```
for elt in root.CarPark:
    el_data = {}
    for child in elt.getchildren():
        el_data[child.tag] = child
    data.append(el_data)
```

Which returns something like 
[{'{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}AccessPoints': http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}AccessPoints at 0x1150a8cd0>,
  '{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}Address': 'Nunnery Lane--York--Yorkshire',
  '{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkAdditionalData': http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkAdditionalData at 0x1150a8d20>,
  '{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkName': 'Nunnery Lane',

...

But when I try to drop it into a dataframe:

{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}AccessPoints        [[[, , ], [, , ], [, , ]], [[, , ], [, , ], [,...
{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}Address                           [[[Nunnery Lane--York--Yorkshire]]]
{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkAdditionalData                                               [[[]]]
{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkName                                        [[[Nunnery Lane]]]
{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkOperator                                                [[[]]]
{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}CarParkRef                                                    [[[3]]]
{http://www.transportdirect.info/carparking}DateRecordLastUpdated                                     [[[2013-06-18]]]

What's the extra step I'm missing to clean it up so it works?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is it that you need to clean up so it works?

Comment: you need to make sure that you are adding strings (even though thye print like strings), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922432/parsing-xml-to-pandas-data-frame-throws-memory-error, seomthing like ``el_data[child.tag] = [ c.text for c in child ]``