# Is there a more efficient way to get data from this xml file to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, xml, pandas

We have some data stored in a number of xml files. An example of the start of the data is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PTW xmlns:ptw="http://www.ptw.de/QUICKCHECK">
  <Version>1.1.0.0</Version>
  <LastModified>2009-10-20 13:45:50</LastModified>
  <Content>
    <TrendData id="730329885" date="2009-10-19 06:35:21" device="00001">
  <Worklist id="472561931">
    <Name>new Worklist</Name>
    <AdminData id="1295858653">
      <AdminValues>
        <TreatmentUnit>Linac1</TreatmentUnit>
        <Protocol Flat="1" Sym="1">Userdefined</Protocol>
        <Modality>Photons</Modality>
        <Energy>12</Energy>
        <Fieldsize>200x200</Fieldsize>
        <SDD>1000</SDD>
        <Gantry>0</Gantry>
        <Wedge>0</Wedge>
        <MU>0</MU>
        <My>1</My>
        <Info />
        <Comment />
      </AdminValues>
      <AnalyzeParams>
        <CAX>
          <Min>9.7000E+01</Min>
          <Max>1.0300E+02</Max>
          <Target>1.0000E+02</Target>
          <Norm>1.0081E+02</Norm>
        </CAX>........ etc etc
```

At the moment I have a function to convert some of the contents in to a pandas dataframe which starts as follows:

```
def qcw_to_df(filename):
    """Read data from a qcw file and returns a Pandas DataFrame
    Use as dataset = parse_qcw(file)"""

    # open the data file
    xmlData = etree.parse(filename)

    trendData = xmlData.findall("//TrendData")
```

I then create an empty list for each of the parameters that I want for each measurement:

```
    date = []
    time = []
    linac = []
    modality = []
    energy = []
    fieldsize = []
    CAX = []
    flatness = []
    symmetryGT = []
    symmetryAB = []
    bqf = []
    measCAX = []
    G10 = []
    L10 = []
    T10 = []
    R10 = []
    G20 = []
    L20 = []
    T20 = []
    R20 = []
    E1 = []
    E2 = []
    E3 = []
    E4 = []
    Temp = []
    Pressure = []
```

...and the read the data file appending each measurement to the appropriate list

```
    for meas in trendData:

        linac_id = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/TreatmentUnit")
        modality_id = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/Modality")
        energy_id = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/Energy")
        fieldsize_id = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/Fieldsize")
                        # first, get the data in the "tags" of the record
                        # need to split datetime into separate date and time fields
                        # names starting read_ are the raw data from the qw file.
        read_measDate = meas.attrib['date']
        read_date = dateutil.parser.parse(read_measDate)
        date.append(read_date)

        read_TreatmentUnit = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/TreatmentUnit")
        linac.append(read_TreatmentUnit)

        read_Modality = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/Modality")
        modality.append(read_Modality)

        read_Energy = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/Energy")
    energy.append(read_Energy)

        read_Fieldsize = meas.findtext("Worklist/AdminData/AdminValues/Fieldsize")
    fieldsize.append(read_Fieldsize)

        # measured values
        read_CAX = meas.findtext("MeasData/AnalyzeValues/CAX/Value")
        if read_CAX == "0.0000E+00":
            read_CAX = ""
        else:
            read_CAX = float(read_CAX)
        CAX.append(read_CAX)

        read_Flatness = meas.findtext("MeasData/AnalyzeValues/Flatness/Value")
        if read_Flatness == "0.0000E+00":
            read_Flatness = ""
        else:
            read_Flatness = float(read_Flatness)
        flatness.append(read_Flatness)
```

This continues for each of the measurements we need to read out
Finally once the each has been read a dataframe is constructed from each of the lists

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':date, 'linac':linac, 'modality':modality, 'energy':energy, 'fieldsize':fieldsize, 'CAX':CAX,
              'flatness':flatness, 'symmetryGT':symmetryGT, 'symmetryAB':symmetryAB, 'bqf':bqf, 'measCAX':measCAX,
              'G10':G10, 'L10':L10, 'T10':T10, 'R10':R10, 'G20':G20, 'L20':L20, 'T20':T20, 'R20':R20, 'E1':E1,
              'E2':E2, 'E3':E3, 'E4':E4, 'Temp':Temp, 'Pressure':Pressure})
df = df.set_index('date')
return df
```

Although this works it does strike me as probably quite inefficient. It also means that if I want to extract other data that is in the file I have to add in another empty list, another findtext line and extend the line which creates the dataframe.

Is there a more efficient way of extracting all the data from the file without having to specifically name each item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML to pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947968/xml-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: i'm not sure how the answer given above is relevant.